# How can i correctly require a text file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I seem to be having trouble with Rails finding the appropriate path to a textfile I would like to load into memory for processing, for a personal learning project.

```
require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/english.txt"
```

or

```
require "/lib/english.txt"
```

are not working.

The textfile is located in the `lib` directory.

I am trying to load it from a simple controller. I continue to get errors:

```
MissingSourceFile in EntriesController#anagram
no such file to load -- /Users/me/Sites/cvtest/lib/english.txt
```

The above path is actually where the file is located according to my computer's info (OSX).  What is it that I am doing incorrectly?  Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to read the text, or run ruby from inside the file?

Comment: im trying to have ruby read in the text.  I was able to achieve it as a stand-alone ruby application, but I am now trying to pull it all up online. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file contains Ruby code, change the extension to rb. Chances are rails will just load the file automatically without any require being necessary. At worst `require 'english'` or `require 'lib/english'` should be all you need.

require is for loading Ruby code extensions, libraries and what-have-you.

If english.txt doesn't contain valid Ruby code, then require isn't what you're looking for, there's nothing to see here, move along. Investigate the many wonders of the File class.

Comment: thank you. I'll look it up.  It is just a .txt file of words with no ruby code in it.  I'll slow down and pay attention :)

Answer (score 2):

`File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/english.txt")` should do it.

`require` is for including Ruby code, such as including a Module in a Class.

Comment: Thank you.  I am learning Ruby & Rails from the beginning, but I just had to get some instant gratification.